# Python subprocess, usage of the shell argument

Tags: python, subprocess

Looking at http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments I made the assumption that unless you use `shell=True`, there is no ability to use `rm`,`cp`,`mv` etc.  Maybe the documentation is out-of-date as they are feeding the call method with a string, where it should be a list.  But using `shell=False` certainly doesn't prevent the usage of said shell commands.

> shell=False disables all shell based features

After looking at subprocess.py, I can see that all that argument does is add `["/bin/sh", "-c"]` to the start of the argument string.

Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: You're really missing the point of using Python if you're shelling out to use `rm`, `cp` and `mv`. Try using the myriad of in-built, platform-agnostic methods contained in os and [shutil](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) modules

Comment: I know full well of these and use them frequently, I'm writing something that I need to prevent from being hacked with shell commands, such as the ones above.

Comment: please accept my apologies. Remember then that these commands are not part of the shell (like they are in DOS) but executables in /bin. The shell sometimes has replacements, such as `echo` in Bash. Good luck :)

Comment: You seriously don't want to be executing arbitrary commands passed from a user, unless they're the owner of the system you're helping them to administrate with your tool.

Comment: i guess that's the whole point of the OPs assumption of preventing that by using `shell=False` and after looking into it he wonders what else if not exactly that, this option is good for! ;-) jm2c

Comment: It's for a company intranet, to no big worries for hacking, just basic sanitising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shell features they are talking about are things like `|` pipes, `*` globs and other wildcards, stdout/stderr redirects with `>` or `2>`, `<(process substitution)` etc.  They are not talking about other commands/programs such as mv, grep, etc.

Comment: Or things like `cd`. Note that on other systems, like Windows, there might not be executables for `mv` etc. so you might have to execute it in a shell context to make it work. But for file stuff it’s better to use Python’s built-in functions.

Comment: +1 Yep, just checked that out and can see the difference now.  Thanks, will mark as answer after the timeout.